Cocoa application produces a lot of "inactive" memory
I am developing software in Objective-C that reads files in chunks and processes them. I noticed with very large files it slows down a lot. Looking in activity monitor it's pretty clear what's going on. When in the system memory tab, the pie chart shows what the memory is used for. When running my application, the blue part of the chart fills up entirely until there is no green left. Once the green is gone, it starts doing a ton of page-outs and the disk starts being used to it's maximum.
From my understanding the inactive memory is memory that was used by an application and is left allocated when that application closes and given back to the application when it opens again. I am using ARC and for every malloc and calloc I use free to make sure everything is freed as soon as possible. When I look in Instruments, it shows the memory is all freed and there are no leaks. I assume Mac OS is marking the memory I used as inactive, maybe it thinks my application is going to need it again. The loop that's causing the problem is an auto-release pool so I would expect it to free up the memory properly.
Here's code that replicates the issue:
//
//  main.m
//  memory issue
//
//  Created by Lasse Lauwerys on 21/04/24.
//  Copyright (c) 2024 Lasse Lauwerys. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSLog(@"Reading file...");
        UInt32 bufferSize = 200000000;
        NSFileHandle *fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:@"/path/to/large/file"];
        UInt64 bytesToProcess;
        NSData *data;
        do @autoreleasepool { // This loop reads the file into ram in chunks of 200MB and frees it after each iteration.
            bytesToProcess = [data = [fileHandle readDataOfLength:bufferSize] length];
        } while (bytesToProcess);
        NSLog(@"Finsihed!");
    }
    return 0;
}

It fills the inactive memory to 100% even with just a 2GB file.
I can't find any helpful info about this on Google. I don't think it's a memory leak as the inactive memory is supposed to be like free memory in case it's necessary.
The purge command frees up the memory and stops the page-outs, making everything fast again. But that doesn't stay for long, you can visually see the blue area grow and after a couple seconds it's full again.
Is this caused by malloc or by creating instances of Objective-C classes? How can I stop it from marking the freed memory as inactive?

What's inside/outside the auto-release pool loop? Post a [mre] please.

Are you using any CoreGraphics methods ? As the memory is not always release immediately and can lead to memory shortage .

@Willeke I created a sample code and tested it. This is all the code necessary to fill up the inactive RAM in just a couple seconds. If you set activity monitor to refresh fast you can see the allocated memory grow to 200MB and immediately free that 200MB after having loaded it. The inactive memory grows at the same rate but is never freed.

@PtitXav I'm not using CoreGraphics. I'm pretty sure the "inactive" memory is not allocated memory anymore but it's memory that is reserved in case the application is closed and opened again but it's freed when other applications need it. The problem is that it's producing so much inactive memory while running that it starts paging immediately and that ruins the file read speeds. The only solution I have now is constantly running the purge command to clean the inactive memory, but that's a bad solution.

Use NSInputStream instead of NSData for reading file. And buffer size should be equal to memory page size.

I tried your code and I don't see any memory issues. Do you have any diagnostic tools enabled like zombies? What "activity monitor" do you mean, where is the pie chart? What is your macOS version and hardware?
